# Finding an index of an element in a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have done a search for finding an index of an element in a string array on this forum. The solutions that I found uses the following method:

Array.IndexOf

I'm new to C# and I haven't heard of this method yet. I can find an index for integers. However I struggling to find a solutions for string type arrays.

Here is the code I use to find the index for integers:

```
public int Search(int testValue)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < test.Length && testValue != test[i])
        i++;
    if(i == test.Length)
        i = -1;
    return i;
}
```

How do I modify the above to be able to use for string type array, or is there another simply method that will do the trick?

Comment: You just need to change type of your parameter to string.BTW, why are you trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: You have heard of the method now so why are you not using it now? Also as a general piece of advice for asking questions make sure the code you provide is complete - at the moment I can guess what `test` is but you should make it clear so that people can just copy paste your code to test it without needing to add parts. Even doing it your way passing the array in as a parameter to the `Search` method would probably make sense (much as the `Array.IndexOf` does. And as a last note http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx is the docs for that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need following example. Let me know, if you need other example or looking for other solution.

```
string[] vals = { "val1", "val2" ,"val3"};
int idx = Array.IndexOf(vals, "val2");
```